# Derivative of left-multiplication in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, differential

Given two maps between sets $f \colon X \to Y$ and $g \colon Y \to Z$, we define the pullback of $g$ by $f$ as $f^*g := g \circ f$.

Given a smooth map between manifolds $F \colon M \to N$ of dimensions $m$ and $n$, respectively, we define its differential (or derivative) at $p \in M$ by a map $d_pF \colon T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$ given by $$d_pF(X_p) := X_pF^*,$$ that is, $d_pF(X_p)f = X_p(f \circ F)$ where $f \in C^\infty_p(M)$.

A curve in a manifold $M$ is a smooth map $c \colon I \to M$ where $I$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$. The velocity of $c$ at $t_0 \in I$ is the tangent vector given by $$c'(t_0) := d_{t_0}c\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t_0}\right) \in T_{c(t_0)}M.$$

Using these definitions, we can prove the following theorem:

> Let $F \colon M \to N$ be a smooth map of manifolds, $p \in M$ and $X_p \in T_pM$. If $c$ is a curve starting at $p$ (that is, $c(0) = p$) in $M$ with velocity $X_p$ at $p$ (i.e., $c'(0) = X_p$), then $$d_pF(X_p) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0 (F \circ c)^*(t).$$

Knowing about this result and about these definitions (that I wrote here so that we all are in the same terms, since there is a billion ways to define these concepts), I need help proving:

> Prove that the derivative of the left multiplication by $g \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, $l_g \colon GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \to GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, is also left multiplication by $g$.

I'm stuck, i've tried writing the definition and do some calculations by I always get nowhere.

Comment: Do you know how to represent a tangent vector of $GL(n, \mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $l_g$ is the restriction to $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ of the linear map$$\begin{array}{rccc}l_g\colon&\Bbb R^{n\times n}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^{n\times n}\\&M&\mapsto&gM.\end{array}$$And when you differentiate a linear map $f$ at any point of its domain, you always get $f$ once again.

---

If you really want to apply that theorem, take $p\in GL(n,\Bbb R)$, take $v\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, and take a curve $c\colon(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\longrightarrow GL(n,\Bbb R)$ such that $c(0)=p$ and that $c'(0)=v$. Then$$(\forall t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)):l_g(c(t))=gc(t),$$and, since multiplication by $g$ is a linear map,$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}gc(t)=g.\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}c(t)=g.v.$$So, $D_pl_g(v)=g.v=l_g(v)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i would like to see the computation using the theorem explicitly. That's what i want to learn (to use the theorem).

Comment: @JeffersonJohnes Done.

Comment: Thanks! I've alredy seen this proof in Loring W. Tu's Introduction to Manifolds, but I'm having some trouble in understanding it.

Take some $f \in C_p^\infty(GL(n,\mathbb{R}))$. If we apply it in the last equality of your answer we have $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0 (f \circ gc)(t) = g\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0 f\circ c.$$ This equality would be valid if $f \circ l_g \circ c = l_g \circ f \circ c$ but this is not true in general, right?

Comment: Indeed. And I don't understand where$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}(f\circ gc)(t)=g\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}(f\circ c)(t)$$comes from.

Comment: From the definition, no? If $c$ is a curve, $(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0} c)f := \frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0} (f \circ c)$ (just combine the definition differential of a map with the definition of velocity vector, given in the original question).

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know the meaning of the notation $\left(\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t_0}\right)f$.

Answer (score 0):

> Then$$(\forall t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)):l_g(c(t))=gc(t),$$and, since multiplication by $g$ is a linear map,$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}gc(t)=g.\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}c(t)=g.v.$$So, $D_pl_g(v)=g.v=l_g(v)$.

To clarify this point. For any linear function $L$ the derivative as $t$ goes to $0$ is explicitly given by $\lim \frac{L(c(t))-L(c(0)}{t}$. Since $L$ is linear, we can rearrange it as $L(\frac{c(t)-c(0)}{t})$ for all t. And because we know linear functions are continuous the limit may be pulled in, giving $L(c'(0))$.

Another way to say this is $\frac{A(v+hw)-A(v)}{h} = \frac{A(v)+A(hw)-A(v)}{h}=\frac{hA(w)}{h} = A(w)$ and apply limit as $h$ goes to $0$ to both sides.

Comment: On mobile. So someone please edit with proper LaTeX. Thanks.